# Sql Server retrieve duplicate rows across columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, count, duplicates, having

**Table 1**

```
ColumnA - Column B   Column C

111         Null        AA
111         Null        BB
222         Null        CC
333         555,222     DD
444         Null        EE
666         777         FF
888         777         GG
```

I need to print all the rows

where number in Column A is more than twice 
Where number in column A matches with number in column b and occurrence is more than once (row 3 on column A is matching with row four of column b)

**Expected output**

```
111         Null        AA
111         Null        BB
222         Null        CC
333         555,222     DD
```

Comment: If you post your attempt it's easier to fix it than to rewrite it from scratch...

Answer (score 1):

For getting distinct record from table you can use distinct keyword in query with field name

> Select distinct ColumnA,Column B from Table1

Answer (score 0):

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(COLUMNA INT,COLUMNB VARCHAR(30),COLUMNC VARCHAR(30))

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT 111,         Null,        'AA'
UNION ALL
SELECT 111,         Null,        'BB'
UNION ALL
SELECT 222,         Null,        'CC'
UNION ALL
SELECT 333,         '555,222',     'DD'
UNION ALL
SELECT 444,         Null,        'EE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 666,         '777',         'FF'
UNION ALL
SELECT 888,         '777',         'GG'
```

**QUERY**

I have written the logic inside the query

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    -- Get the CSV as rows and count the occurance of ColumnA
    SELECT COLUMNA,LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) 'COLUMNB',COLUMNC,
    COUNT(COLUMNA) OVER(PARTITION BY COLUMNA) CNT 
    FROM  
    (
         -- Select the values to convert into rows from CSV
         SELECT COLUMNA,
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(ISNULL(COLUMNB,''), ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data,
         COLUMNC 
         FROM #TEMP     
    ) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)
-- Find the rows where number of each unique item in ColumnA > 1
-- and ColumnA element exists in ColumnB
SELECT DISTINCT T.*
FROM CTE C
JOIN #TEMP T ON C.COLUMNA=T.COLUMNA 
WHERE CNT > 1
OR C.COLUMNA IN (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMNB FROM CTE)
```

- **[Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5827f/2) to view result**

**RESULT**

[image]

**EDIT**

If you want to get records when only both conditions satisfy, use `AND` instead of `OR` in the last line, ie,

```
AND C.COLUMNA IN (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMNB FROM CTE)
```